# I found a small dead bush,with very hard wood red to black in color was in a gulley on west side of red rock open space

Tags: identification

I found a small dead bush, with very hard wood red to black in color was in a gulley on west side of red rock open space. the living ones I have seen are 3ft to 6ft tall with small fingernail size leaves.

Comment: Did you have a question? Please clarify

Comment: Please add pictures, tell us where you live, what would you like or need to know.  Sounds like a plant ID.  Close ups as well as a picture of entire plant and surrounding environment.  Buds, flowers, close up of leaf edges.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Red Rock Canyon Open Space outside of Colorado Springs CO? Possibly some sort of Manzanita, but pictures are needed.